# convert string to date without changing timezone in the string using java

Tags: java, date

I have a string with timezone included like `2020-11-12T12:00:00-0800`. When I converting into to date in the JAVA time zone automatically changing to IST, can someone help with this? thanks in advance.

```
String s = '2020-11-12T12:00:00-0800'
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
date = format.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the timezone format from the end of the String (letter `Z`).
For example, this will print `Thu Nov 12 06:30:00 CET 2020`

```
String s = "2020-11-12T6:30:00-0800";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
var date = format.parse(s);
System.out.println(date);
```

But if I add the letter `Z` at the end, it will interpret the given timezone and change time to my local timezone, when printed. So this will print `Thu Nov 12 15:30:00 CET 2020`

```
String s = "2020-11-12T6:30:00-0800";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
var date = format.parse(s);
System.out.println(date);
```

More about the patterns can be found in the [JavaDoc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you Oresztesz!, Yes, it's changing to my timezone.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you then don't forget to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the time zone and also moving to the new (since Java 8) api java.time you can use ZonedDateTime

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
```

The result then is

```
String s = "2020-11-12T12:00:00-0800";
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
System.out.println(date);
```

> 2020-11-12T12:00-08:00

Comment: Thank you, Joakim Danielson!